# how to save mysql datatable using sharedpreferences in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, sharedpreferences

I want to save my all data from MYSQL database in my application and retrive it every time when my apps opens even if there is no internet connection. I want to show the data that is already fetched from the database and save it in my app. If database is update then automatically add that data to my app.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any research any approaches towards solving the problem? Show some code

Answer (score 1):

I think you need export MYSQL and create Sqlite database in your application,instead of sharedperferance.

Comment: so i need to make a new sqlite database